# Android, Java. Как можно реализовать действие при касании кнопки, и при этом ещё сделать цикличное выполнение действий при удержании этой кнопки?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

С просто касанием всё понятно:

```java
left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    deleteFig();
                    if (xOfUpperLeftCorner != 0) {
                        xOfUpperLeftCorner--;
                    }

                    try {
                        spawnFig(xOfUpperLeftCorner, yOfUpperLeftCorner, figNum, figState);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                return true;
            }
        });
```

А как на эту же кнопку прикрутить цикличное выполнение этих же действий, пока она **удерживается**?

##### UPD2:

Попробовал вот так:

```java
        right.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    upRight = false;

                    deleteFig();
                    if (xOfUpperLeftCorner != xCells - currentFigWidth) {
                        xOfUpperLeftCorner++;
                    }

                    try {
                        spawnFig(xOfUpperLeftCorner, yOfUpperLeftCorner, figNum, figState);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    upRight = true;
                }

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!upRight) {
                            deleteFig();
                            if (xOfUpperLeftCorner != xCells - currentFigWidth) {
                                xOfUpperLeftCorner++;
                            }

                            try {
                                spawnFig(xOfUpperLeftCorner, yOfUpperLeftCorner, figNum, figState);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 650);


                return true;
            }
        });
```

Работает, но забагованно, много раз срабатывает лишнее.

Comment: Следующие события обрабатывайте, перемещения и вверх с контролем выхода за пределы.

Comment: В цикле что ли? Когда я пытался сделать что-то с циклом, приложение тупо зависало, а потом "приложение не отвечает"

Comment: так это азы. не понятно что вы делаете в цикле, в слушателе запускайте и останавливайте поток, а в нем уже зацикливайтесь

Comment: Чёт у меня не работает. Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @HumanNo1 как мне известно MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN выполняется только 1 раз. вам скорее всего нужно при ACTION_DOWN запустить какой либо поток или службу где будет выполнятся нужный вам цикл и какой либо периодичностью, а при ACTION_UP или ACTION_CANCEL  вы должны прерывать данный поток/службу

Comment: @Tiarait Я тоже об этом уже узнал. Сейчас обновлю вопрос, получилось что-то вроде, но оно всё равно немного забагованное.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, для начала нам нужна некая вьюшка `private View right`, переменная, что обозначает отпускание `private boolean upRight = false` и сам поток, где будет цикл:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!upRight) {
                //сюда ваш код
                Thread.sleep(650);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //handle the exception
        }
    }
};
```

И дальше задаем слушатель нажатия `TouchListener` на вью `right`:

```
right.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            upRight = false;
            thread.start();
        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            upRight = true;
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Если внутри потока нужны действия над вью (изменение размера, цвета и  т. д.), то нам это нужно делать в основном потоке:

```
if (getActivity() != null) getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
    //здесь ваш код
});
```

---

На самом деле от `upRight` можно отказаться, а `while (!upRight)` заменить на другой `while`.

Comment: Вот тут: ```if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { upRight = false; thread.start(); }``` оно выбросило ```IllegalThreadStateException```

Comment: вы случайно больше нигде не используете `thread.start()`? внутри потока используете `runOnUiThread` или там нет взаимодействий с интерфейсом?

Comment: runOnUiThread нет. Там только метод spawnFig, который взаимодействует с интерфейсом.

Comment: Советую почитать про потоки. поскольку вашу задачу можно решить только в фоне, иначе при нажатии на кнопку будет выполнятся код и покуда код не выполнится то ввесь интерфейс будет заморожен, а поскольку интерфейс заморожен то и отпустить кнопку мы не можем. Если spawnFig взаимодействует с интерфейсом (Ui), а для работы с интерфейсом нужно использовать основной поток то логично обернуть spawnFig в runOnUiThread

Comment: А можно в runOnUIThread юзать Thread.sleep? Я просто обернул задержку и методы, которые работают с UI, в runOnUiThread, и приложение "не отвечает"

Comment: Конечно нельзя - задача, переданная в `runOnUiThread()` выполняется в UI-потоке и его нельзя усыплять или сильно нагружать. А поток нужно каждый раз создавать заново перед запуском (ака `thread = new Thread()`), повторно запустить его нельзя, из-за этого ошибка `IllegalThreadStateException`